# Valgrind install another fsroot

Tags: mips, valgrind

The system under which you are compiling Valgrind for `mips`. System on img disk, which I mount to `/mnt/mount_dir` directory. When configuring valgrind ask `--prefix=/mnt/mount_dir` is the path to the root, then `make` and `make install`. But when starting already on the emulated system valgrind complains it can't find `memchek`, of course, because he is looking in the directory `/mnt/mount_dir/lib/valgrind/memcheck-mips32-linux`, and need in `/lib/valgrind/memcheck-mips32-linux`. What `prefix` should be placed on the step of the configuration so that valgrind thought that `/mnt/mount_dir` it's a `/` root?